# Ubuntu Apache doesn't redirect http to https

Tags: python, apache, redirect, https

im using Apache/2.2.15 (unix)
i had change the server to work on https, its work fine except a small warning, the server hostname is example and the cert CN is example.domain , so the HTTPS sign has red line on it.
im trying to redirect HTTP to HTTPS, but it's doesn't work.
i had read a lot, nothing solved it.

my httpd.conf file (only relevant part) :

```
<virtualHost *:80>

ServerName name

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/* [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
<VirtualHost>
```

my ssl.conf file is configured with virtualHost *:443 and ill post it on demand.

my error log file after the change and restart the httpd:

```
[error] Exception keyerror: keyerror(140406319183840,) in module 'threading' from '/usr/lib64/python2/threading.pyc' ignored
[notice] caucht SIGTERM, shutting down
[notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (weapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication...
[notice] Digest: done
[warn] mod_wsgi: compiled for paython/2.6.2
[warn] mod_wsgi:runtime using python/2.6.2
```

the only thing i got from this error log is that i dont have the file /usr/lib64/python2/threading.pyc

thank you!

Comment: Where did it say you didn't have `threading.pyc`? I see a warning FROM `threading.pyc` saying `KeyError` on key `140406319183840`?

Comment: i had looked for the file, it missing from the file system

Comment: I don't know how mod_wsgi works, but according to what i see I have a feeling that you actually do have `threading.pyc`, otherwise the error shouldn't be able to say `in module 'threading'`.

Comment: i had checked it again, i do not have it. 
someone has any idea whats that file is ?

Comment: Again, are you sure THAT is the problem? This probably isn't the case here but the file might run in a container or a virtual bubble. Thus not being there when you look for it. Also your redirect URL should be something along the lines of `RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]` or use `Redirect permanent / https://{SERVER_NAME}`

Comment: we had solved the issue ! we configured it to listen to port 80. thank you all!

Comment: Make sure you listen to port 80, `Listen 80 <VirtualHost *:80>`

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by listening on port 80 like so:

```
Listen 80 <VirtualHost *:80>
```

Answer found in the comments from @bogin @ratskin